# "Context Cue", or "Context Clue"

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a mock business plan for a translation company. Alongside the text they have to translate, there is some accompanying media, so they can pull more information out of the sentences (plurals, etc, that vary in languages)

I want to describe these additional media as context c(l)ues, but I'm not sure of the correct spelling. I've seen both used online.

Which version is the most correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I think you want 'cues'. A 'cue' is a prompt. Context cues would  I assume be peripheral ideas and text that one could call upon.

A 'clue' is something altogether different and is something detectives follow when investigating a crime. e.g. 'The only clue they had to work on were some fingerprints on the door handle'.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was that, I just thought about it too hard ^^